# How to solve this related rates problem with trapezoids?

Tags: calculus

A water trough is 9 m long and has a cross-section in the shape of an isosceles trapezoid that is 30 cm wide at the bottom, 70 cm wide at the top, and has height 40 cm. If the trough is being filled with water at the rate of 0.2 m3/min how fast is the water level rising when the water is 20 cm deep?

Comment: Refer to the details at the link below . There is more detailed solution there with drawings for better understanding. http://www.math.illinois.edu/~yeakel2/sp/relrates.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You solve it in the usual way.  You need to compute $V(h)$, the volume of water in the trough when the height of the water is $h$.  Then invert it to get $h(V)$.  You are asked for $\frac {dh}{dt}$ at a particular value of $h$ and are given $\frac {dV}{dt}$.  Differentiate with respect to $t$, use the chain rule, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The flow rate $\dot{q}$ in [m^3/s] is defined as $$ \dot{q} = v\,A $$ where $v$ is the speed (water level rising) and $A$ the cross section area.

$\rightarrow$ Solve the above for $v$.